# Does it make sense to use AsyncTask if onPostExcute is not used?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, request, ui-thread

in a code snippet I am looking at, a private class which extends `AsyncTask` is used. However the `onPostExecute` method is not used. Only the `doInBackground` method is used and in that method there is a `POST` request made. The question I have is, isn't `AsyncTask` is for updating the UI after doing a job? I mean does it make sense to use it without `onPostExecute`?

(I am not allowed to share any part of the code, so sorry if this is vague.)

Thank you.

Comment: It all depends on your purpose of the AsyncTask. If you feel it's okay without it (or you just don't need it for some reason), then you can leave it empty. But I suggest you to use onPostExecute to do the after doInBackground process such as showing result, etc.

Comment: @SweArmy What can be the purpose tho, if I am not using it?

Comment: That's why it all depends on what are you trying to achieve. For example, if you are parsing JSON with AsyncTask, you can do the parsing in doInBackground and display the result in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the task to be performed. You can perfectly use an AsyncTask without calling **onPostExecute**, but if it doesn't neither use the **onProgressUpdate** method, then it would mean an incorrect use of its purpose, which is to execute a task in a background thread, and notify the result on the UI thread, **or** notify progress updates on the UI thread.

So, if is not using **onPostExecute** or **onProgressUpdate** at all, then probably should be replaced with a [Thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread).

**Also consider** that the AsyncTask class [has been deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) in API 30, therefore may be a good time to refactor such code.

Comment: Thank you this was what I was looking for. I was expecting a suggestion of another concept to use if it wasn't gonna alert the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If the code in `doInBackground` method does not return a value (used only for side effect), for example in your case it is used for `POST` request, Which doses not return a value.

According to Docs:  `onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter.`

Example:

```
class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>{
 @Override
 protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
    //  DO POST REQUEST
     return null;
 }
```

}

Because the **Progress** and **Result** Parameters are `Void` you don't have to override the `onPostExecute(Result)` method.

Comment: Yes but the thing is, why use an AsyncTask then? If you are not gonna alert the UI.

Comment: In that case, you are right it doesn't make sense to use it, I just elaborate just in case u don't know how to use it in the first place. And also it's now deprecated,   you can use **Coroutines** which also has **withContext(Dispactcher.main)** method which achieves the work of **onPostExecute(Result)** but more elegantly and with more benefits.